# Javascript module references collection document in public method

Tags: javascript, meteor

In the Meteor server code below, it prints out the color obtained from the `myCol` when compiled. But the color gets changed by a mongo shell command, and the code is fired again, it fails to print out the new color.
How can it be fixed so that it so that `console.log(color)` prints the "new" color? thx

```
///////sever/food.js

let Milk = function () {
   let color = Meteor.myCol.findOne({food:'milk'}).color;
   return function () {
     console.log (color);
   }
}

export const Food = {
  milk: new Milk()
}


//////server/buy.js
import {Food} from './food';
Food.milk();  // expecting to get the color saved in the collection at the time of calling
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function milk is a local variable that returns a function that prints the color. When calling the milk function from buy.js, you are only calling the log, and not fetching the document from the db again, thus it has the old value.

If all you want to do is get the color of the milk and log it, I would write the milk function like this (ES6), in food.js:

```
const milkColor = () => {
  let milk = myCol.findOne({food: 'milk'});
  const color = milk?milk.color:undefined;
  console.log(color);
}

export const Food = {
  milk: milkColor
}
```

then, in buy.js:

```
import {Food} from './food';
Food.milkColor();
```